codehigh, for verbatim text in tabularray table
In the tabularray package documentation is suggested that for the verbatim text in tables should be used \fakeverb instruction defined in the codehigh package instead of \verb.
Using it I' faced with tow problems:

verb doesn't work anymore (for example used out of tables)
in cases when text use letters like č, ć, ž, š, đ, this this letters doesn't show up or are in the case when is used T1 font encoding are appears with  some strange symbols

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{codehigh}

\begin{document}
my name is Žarko, my name is \fakeverb{Žarko}
\end{document}


Do anyone know a cure for this?

Not an answer, but it seems the issue reduces to \tl_set:Nn \l_zarko_tl { Žarko } \tl_to_str:N \l_zarko_tl which produces the same thing

Or equivalently, \detokenize{Žarko}
